# How to update mysql row with row index and column name?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am iterating through the rows of a table, and with each iteration I want to update the "ID" column.

The problem is going through a table of points and updating the "Link ID" (the road link the point it located on). The examples I've seen with updating a specific row/column use the value in the row to identify what to change, however I want to just change the row based off knowing the row's position.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what problem solving are you doing, give more info plz

Comment: `show create table xxx` ... document it, and improve question :>

Comment: I'd assume it would be something like this, no? `UPDATE yourTable SET yourIDFieldName = value WHERE yourIDField = value`. Unless I've misunderstood you.

Comment: Most likely the `ID` column is a table primary key that you should not change.

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to mysql and still am very bad at the basics - The problem is going through a table of points and updating the "Link ID" (the road link the point it located on). The examples I've seen with updating a specific row/column use the value in the row to identify what to change, however I want to just change the row based off knowing the row's position.

Comment: `show create table xxx`  take that output, [edit] question with that info, provide some sample data

Comment: Updating a point's link id per the point and *what else*.

Comment: Presumably you are *looking up* the id of the link that is under a point? If so then you have a table point_link(p,lid) *and* a table allowing you to map a point to a link. Eg link(lid,pstart,pfinish). Please per the other comments clearly explain what things you are dealing with and what you want to do with them, and give a complete example of tables, what a row of each says in terms of an application situation, and example input and desired output values.